# React-router You cannot push the same route... force History.push / reload component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get my search bar working correctly.
When making a search, router sends me to /list/(whatever I searched for)

The searchbar is changing my route programmatically like so:

```
var pathname = '/list/';
        var query = {
            q: this.state.searchBar
        };
        hashHistory.push({pathname, query});
```

/list/:q has a componentDidMount function that sends a GET request to a database, but if I make a new search while allready on '/list/:q' the url gets updated but the component is not reloaded.

My problem: 
How can I force my component to reload when making a new search while already on the search route /'list/:q'?

Relevant code:
[Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/NSaK7PKK)

Comment: Have you tried using `componentWillReceiveProps`?

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Seems I need to read the lifecycle methods better.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul S suggested, using componentWillReceiveProps solved my problem.